# How to refer GDG generation if generation is created in step 2 and same i refer in step 3

Tags: mainframe, jcl

I have faced an issue in GDG generation in production.

New generation is created in STEP 2:

```
//INP DD DSN=sample.test(+1),  
//      DISP=(,CATLG,KEEP),                     
//       SPACE=(CYL,(50,20),RLSE),               
//       DCB=(RECFM=FB,LRECL=1020,BLKSIZE=4080)
```

The same generation is refered in STEP 3:

```
//step3 exec PGM=SORT                               
//SORTIN   DD DSN=sample.test(+1),    
//            DISP=SHR                                 
//SORTOUT  DD DSN=xxxx.yyyy,     
//            DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE),                 
//            UNIT=(SYSDA,9),DCB=(RECFM=FB,LRECL=132), 
//            SPACE=(CYL,(50,20),RLSE)
```

I gave like this, but fails with JCL error.

Can anyone help on why this fails?

As per theory once job has completed only. We have to refer with 0th version. In Same job we have to refer with +1 Version. If i changed to 0th version in step 3 then the job ran fine.

Comment: What is the JCL error you're seeing?  Is it "dataset not found" or is it something else?

Comment: "DISP FIELD INCOMPATIBLE WITH DSNAME"

Comment: Please cut/paste the job log and system messages. However, I believe you should be using DISP=OLD in STEP3. Once you post the log and messages, if the NEW is an issue, I will write a proper answer.

Comment: Is this a first run (i.e. has it changed) or has the job been run multiple times ??, is the GDG defined ???

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the message number, IEF… 
The default disposition in the INP step is NEW so the message indicates that the dataset already exists - without seeing the other steps in the deck it's hard to help.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea about GDG's is correct. In this case you will get a JCL error if the **step** creating the GDG **fails** or is **skipped** because of COND / IF statement or Step2 does not open the GDG (Non SMS ???), then step3 will get a JCL error because sample.test(+1) does not exist. There are other possibilities that could cause a JCL error (e.g. can not allocate the dataset) but I think this is the most likely. It would be easier if full JCL / Error messages where listed

There are two possible solutions (in most cases choose **option 1 or 2**)

1. Add a **IEBGENER** step1a to create the GDG before step2, this should ensure the GDG is created.
2. Add a cond to step 3

   //step3 exec PGM=SORT,COND=(0,NE)
3. Change disp to DISP=(,CATLG,CATLG), (if the step failed)

   //INP DD DSN=sample.test(+1),
   //      DISP=(,CATLG,CATLG),

   Only choose option 2 if you want the Output if the job fails.

I would change DISP=(,CATLG,KEEP) to one of DISP=(,CATLG), DISP=(,CATLG,DELETE) or DISP=(,CATLG,CATLG). In the old days KEEP alowed you to create an uncatlogued datasets.

Alternately SMS might be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong GDG index.
You should use (0) index to refer the lastest added dataset to the GDG.

(+1) indicates that a new dataset should be added to the GDG.

More information: [IBM Retrieving a Generation Data Set](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r11/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r11.ieab500/iea2b550197.htm)

Comment: GDG calculation are done at the start of the job, so +1 is correct when refering to a GDG created in a previous step.

Comment: Documentation on that? I have tried that by error and it didn't work. Maybe it's a scheduler thing.

Comment: From your link: Refer to generation data sets in a deferred roll-in state by their relative number, such as (+1), within the job that creates it. The Statement is a bit hard to understand I know. I have had 20+ years working with JCL. I suspect the +1 GDG was not actually created in step2, possible causes include File not opened by ther program, step bypassed (check cond), step failed (and step3 has cond=even). A very close look at the messages should reveal if one these happenend. See my answer for possible solutions'

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to interpret the exact issue with limited information about which DD statement is in error.  I think you have the right idea regarding the use of +1 in your example.  I don't believe that is the issue with your error.

I suspect that the error is with the first DD's Abnormal Disposition of KEEP on the //INP DD statement.  In effect, You are asking to create a NEW gdg dataset that will be cataloged only if the step 2 executes normally.  If the job abends in step 2, you are asking the system for KEEP of a GDG dataset **that isn't registered in the system catalog yet**.  I think DISP=(,CATLG,CATLG) would be a more appropriate coding for the //INP DD statement in this scenario.

Normally you would use KEEP in situations where the dataset already exists and should be retained.

However, if your shop is using SMS-managed datasets, KEEP is treated as CATLG because all SMS managed datasets must be cataloged.  If that is the situation, then this response may not apply to your specific situation. It doesn't appear from your example that SMS is a factor here.